# enum values from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, enums

I have a `enum` column in my table and I am trying to get out the values I have set in the table in a drop down. So first I have written this query to get the `column_type` and `column_name`

```
"SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`,`DATA_TYPE`,`COLUMN_TYPE` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='devsbh' AND `TABLE_NAME`='modules' AND `COLUMN_NAME` NOT IN ('created_at', 'updated_at')"
```

then I do this to get out the enum values like so

```
<?php 
   $regex = "/'(.*?)'/";
   preg_match_all( $regex , $modules->COLUMN_TYPE , $enum_array );
   $enum_fields = $enum_array[1];
?>
```

and I display like so

PS:Using laravel's blade template engine.

```
{!! Form::select($modules->COLUMN_NAME,$enum_fields) !!}
```

Everything is correct up until here. When I try to store it tries too save as for Y => 0 and for N => 1. How can I get the key => value same as enum value?

the values of `$enum_fields` as per the console is [0]=>Y , [1]=>N.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `array_combine` method to make the key and the value of the array same like so

```
<?php
     $regex = "/'(.*?)'/";
     preg_match_all( $regex , $modules->COLUMN_TYPE , $enum_array );
     $keyValueSame = array_combine($enum_array[1],$enum_array[1]);
 ?>
```

now the key and value of the $keyValueSame array  will have the same value.

the values of $keyValueSame as per the console is [Y]=>Y , [N]=>N.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off just hard coding the enumerations into your codebase.

Assuming you are using MySQL, the idea behind enumerations is really to restrict the values in the column to a specific set - basically saying "if the value is not one of these strings, don't allow it.".

Enumerations are not designed to be changed often (if at all) - in fact, you may find issues if you do try to alter them it - it can take some database gymnastics to alter them especially if you have lots of records.

If your "lookup" data will change, and you need it to be database stored, make the column a foreign key to another table containing your lookup fields.

If you are stuck with the enumerations, just hard code the list in your dropdown.